# Help combining "AND" and "OR" into one formula

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, workflow, remedyforce

In Remedyforce (which uses Salesforce) I am trying to create a formula for an email alert to be used when incidents in certain queues are closed. The standard formula for this (without looking at the queues) is:

({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__state__c} = False) && ({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__followUp__c} = False) && (ISBLANK( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDetail__c}) )

I only want this workflow to run if the incident's "queue" field is populated with one of 3 options.  Something along the lines of this:

({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__state__c} = False) && ({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__followUp__c} = False) && (ISBLANK( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDetail__c}) ) && ({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC CDR') || ({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC KOP') || ({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC UNI')

I am thinking this wont work, because as soon as it hits the first OR, then it will ignore the first part (so it would probably run when these incidents are not closed). Can someone show me what the correct syntax would be so it properly looks at the first 3 ANDs and only runs if one of the 3 ORs is correct?

Comment: Add extra brackets around the whole sequence of ORs.

Answer (score 2):

Separate out the last three items with extra brackets:

```
{!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__state__c} = False && 
{!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__followUp__c} = False && 
ISBLANK( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDetail__c}) && 
( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC CDR' || 
  {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC KOP' || 
  {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC UNI' )
```

An alternate that may improve readability is to use `AND` and `OR` functions:

```
AND (
  {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__state__c} = False, 
  {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__followUp__c} = False, 
  ISBLANK( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDetail__c}), 
  OR ( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC CDR' , 
     {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC KOP' ,
     {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC UNI' )
)
```

Finally, a third version inspired by sfdxfox's comment:

```
AND ( NOT ({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__state__c}),
      NOT ({!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__followUp__c}),
      ISBLANK( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDetail__c}), 
      OR ( {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC CDR' , 
           {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC KOP' ,
           {!$Record.BMCServiceDesk__queueName__c} = 'EUC UNI' )
)
```

Comment: +1 Also, recall that a "Boolean is already a Boolean", if those are indeed checkbox fields, no need to add the extra checks, just use NOT (or !) instead.

Comment: Oh yes, good point. I'll add that as a third version. I sometimes leave the ` = True ` stuff in for readability.